# Multiple sites share one IP address: I can't reach special site using Host header

Tags: http, curl

In a book I'm reading now the author shows what HTTP headers mean. Namely he said that there are servers that host multiple web site.

Let's do this:

```
ping fideloper.com
```

We can see the IP address: 198.211.113.202.

Now let's use the IP address only:

```
curl -I 198.211.113.202
```

We catch:

```
$ curl -I 198.211.113.202
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 03 Aug 2017 14:48:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://book.serversforhackers.com/
```

Let’s next see what happens when we add a Host header to the HTTP request:

```
$ curl -I -H "Host: fideloper.com" 198.211.113.202
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public
Date: Thu, 03 Aug 2017 13:23:58 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 30 Dec 2016 22:32:12 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjhVQlk2UWcyRExsaDllVEpJOERaT3dcL2d2aE9mMHV4eUduSjFkQTRKU0R3PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMmcwVUpNSjFETWs1amJaNzhGZXVGZjFPZ3hINUZ1eHNsR0dBV1FvdE9mQ1RFak5IVXBKUEs2aEZzaEhpRHRodE1LcGhFbFI3OTR3NzQxZG9YUlN5WlE9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImRhNTVlZjM5MDYyYjUxMTY0MjBkZjZkYTQ1ZTQ1YmNlNjU3ODYzNGNjZTBjZWUyZWMyMjEzYjZhOWY1MWYyMDUifQ%3D%3D; expires=Thu, 03-Aug-2017 15:23:58 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
X-Fastcgi-Cache: HIT
```

This means that serversforhackers.com is the default site.

Then the author said that we could request Servers for Hackers on the same server:

```
$ curl -I -H "Host: serversforhackers.com” 198.211.113.202
```

Here in the book HTTP/1.1 200 OK is received.

But I receve this:

```
curl -I -H "Host: serversforhackers.com" 198.211.113.202
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 03 Aug 2017 14:55:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://book.serversforhackers.com/
```

Well, the author organized a 301 redirect and uses HTTPS now.

I could do this:

```
curl -I https://serversforhackers.com
```

But this doesn't illustrate the whole idea of what default site is and how Host header can address a special site on a shared IP address.

**Is it still possible somehow to get 200 Ok addressing via IP address?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTTP/1.1, without HTTPS, the `Host` header is the only place where the hostname is sent to the server.

With HTTPS, things are more interesting.

First, your client will normally try to check the server’s TLS certificate against the expected name:

```
$ curl -I -H "Host: book.serverforhackers.com" https://198.211.113.202
curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name (book.serversforhackers.com) does not match target host name '198.211.113.202'
```

Most clients provide a way to override this check. curl has the `-k`/`--insecure` option for that:

```
$ curl -k -I -H "Host: book.serverforhackers.com" https://198.211.113.202
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
[...]
```

But then there’s the second issue. I can’t illustrate it with your example server, but here’s one I found on the Internet:

```
$ curl -k -I https://analytics.usa.gov 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
[...]

$ host analytics.usa.gov | head -n 1
analytics.usa.gov has address 54.240.184.142

$ curl -k -I -H "Host: analytics.usa.gov" https://54.240.184.142
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed
```

This is caused by [server name indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) — a feature of TLS (HTTPS) whereby the hostname is **also** sent in the TLS handshake. It is necessary because the server needs to present the right certificate (for the right hostname) before it can receive any HTTP headers at all. In the example above, when we use `https://54.240.184.142`, curl doesn’t send the correct SNI, and the server refuses the handshake. Other servers might accept the connection but route it to a wrong place, where the `Host` header will end up being ignored.

With curl, you can’t set SNI with a separate option like you set the `Host` header. curl will always take it from the request URL. But curl has a special [`--resolve`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--resolve) option:

> Provide a custom address for a specific host and port pair. Using this, you can make the curl requests(s) use a specified address and prevent the otherwise normally resolved address to be used. Consider it a sort of /etc/hosts alternative provided on the command line.

In this case:

```
$ curl -I --resolve analytics.usa.gov:443:54.240.184.142 https://analytics.usa.gov
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
[...]
```

(443 is the standard TCP port for HTTPS)

If you want to experiment at a lower level, you can use the [`openssl`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/openssl/openssl.1ssl.en.html) tool to establish a raw TLS connection with the right SNI:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 54.240.184.142:443 -servername analytics.usa.gov -crlf
```

You will then be able to type an HTTP request and see the right response:

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: analytics.usa.gov

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
[...]
```

Lastly, note that in HTTP/2, there’s a special header named `:authority` (yes, with a colon) that may be used instead of `Host` by some clients. The distinction between them exists for backward compatibility with HTTP/1.1 and proxies: see [RFC 7540 § 8.1.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.3) and [RFC 7230 § 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3) for details.